# Invalid partition table!

Tags: grub, gparted

[image]

I had a dual booted system (dell inspiron 5000 series). But then I wanted to Remove windows os so I booted from live flash drive and opened gparted and directly deleted windows partition. Now I extended Linux partition (ext4) and rebooted. It showed invalid partition table. So I booted from live CD and tried updating grub. Can you please help me show where I went wrong. I am new to Linux community.

Comment: How did you "extend Linux partition"? Why did you not "delete windows patition" from your runing linux? Please give more information.